# web service Response returns 0

Tags: android, json

In my android app, I am calling a web service when I debug and check the response it always returns a fee(key) value 0 but when I am calling same web service using postman at that time it returns a valid data.

what can be the issue? please help me.

Postman response

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "responsecode": "200",
    "message": "success",
    "response": [
        {
            "class_id": "",
            "name": "Select Class type",
            "fee": 0,
            "minutes": 0
        },
        {
            "class_id": 1,
            "name": "Tenth",
            "fee": "500",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 2,
            "name": "Ninth",
            "fee": "450",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 3,
            "name": "First",
            "fee": "150",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 4,
            "name": "Second",
            "fee": "100",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 5,
            "name": "Third",
            "fee": "150",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 6,
            "name": "Fourth",
            "fee": "30",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 7,
            "name": "Fifth",
            "fee": "50",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 8,
            "name": "Sixth",
            "fee": "50",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 9,
            "name": "Seventh",
            "fee": "40",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 10,
            "name": "Eighth",
            "fee": "60",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 12,
            "name": "Eleventh",
            "fee": "80",
            "minutes": "1"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 13,
            "name": "Twelfth",
            "fee": "100",
            "minutes": "1"
        }
    ]
}

Android debug response:
{
    "status": "true",
    "responsecode": "200",
    "message": "success",
    "response": [
        {
            "class_id": "",
            "name": "Select Class type",
            "fee": 0,
            "minutes": 0
        },
        {
            "class_id": 1,
            "name": "Tenth",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 2,
            "name": "Ninth",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 3,
            "name": "First",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 4,
            "name": "Second",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 5,
            "name": "Third",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 6,
            "name": "Fourth",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 7,
            "name": "Fifth",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 8,
            "name": "Sixth",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 9,
            "name": "Seventh",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 10,
            "name": "Eighth",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 12,
            "name": "Eleventh",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        },
        {
            "class_id": 13,
            "name": "Twelfth",
            "fee": "0",
            "minutes": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Post your model class..

Comment: @Tanuja bisht post your complete code of web services call and parsing of result

Comment: code???????????